# UTF-8 issue with excel

Tags: java, excel, spring, file, utf-8

I am trying to make excel recognize UTF-8 file and exporting file with UTF-8-BOM file with code

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(pathToFile.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
bufferedWriter.write('\ufeff');
bufferedWriter.write(content);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
```

I have this characters

```
みなさん、こんにちは、ここであなたたちを見つけました、これは地球上で最も素晴らしい場所です、パン、空気、水、リンゴ、塩がすべて揃っています。
```

which have issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7yH0.png)

and when I am trying to open created file with excel it is recognizes as ASII instead of UTF-8.
How to make excel open file as UTF-8?

I tried to add bufferedWriter.write('\ufeff'); to make exported file UTF_8_BOM which is not helpful.

Comment: It appears you did everything correctly.  But Windows doesn’t always do a good job of supporting UTF-8.  Do you get different results if you use StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE?

Comment: Check the byte output in the file with a hex editor.  The first few bytes should be `ef bb bf e3 81 bf e3 81 aa e3 81 95`.  The first three are the UTF-8 BOM signature.  What filename do you use?  A `.csv` file with this data opens correctly in Excel.